# Salesforce Low bandwidth tools

Tags: salesforce, web-component, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

Does anyone know a good mechanism for measuring or reporting on page sizes?

I have a low bandwidth (humanitarian client) use case and trying to evaluate my pages, hi-res imagery or other page size issues, across the org. As an example, even a standard Lightning page view seems to be coming in at around 700kb, which seems high.

If there’s something on the AppEchange that would be great, but otherwise any direction in reporting, API tools or creating this through other mechanisms would be really helpful.

I have searched the Salesforce AppExchange, and available metadata/other API and so far haven't found anything. Event Monitoring has logs that help general page load performance and I found an article around improving performance, but haven't found ways to identify SIZE as would be needed for low bandwidth scenarios.

Don't know where to start yet, unfortunately. This could be a programmatic solution, in which case I'd love some direction, but it could also be tools available elsewhere I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome dev tools (F12), in the Network tab you can simulate a low bandwith and long latency connection in order to measure the download time of a web page or web application.

You can also visualize the size and download time of every resources downloaded to identify the biggest images and the most time consumming requests.

In Salesforce, there's an administrative tool call Lightning Usage that can be activated. It generates diffrente dashboard and performance stats by page. You can found some screenshots in that Salesforce description of the service:  https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/10/understanding-experienced-page-time.html. The metric EPT could meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks! This is great, but sounds like we don't know of any way to analyze that within Salesforce, programmatically or otherwise. Trying to find a method that can scale rather than going page by page.